# JScrollPane not scrolling to show whole pannel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

I have developed a Code which will display a panel & added a scrollpane which will scroll down if panel size is more than the visible region.

My code is

```
    CT3= new CT3TycoDULocalPanel(anexflag1,anexflag2);
    
    cnt =(JPanel)getContentPane ();
    cnt.setLayout (null);
                        
    pane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    pane.add (CT3,BorderLayout.CENTER);

    scPane = new JScrollPane(CT3); 
    scPane.setLayout(null);
    scPane.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    scPane.setBounds(20,12,550,600);

    scp=scPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
    scp.setBounds (528,0,20,600);
    scp.addAdjustmentListener (this);
    
    scPane.setViewportView(CT3);
    scPane.add(scp);
    scPane.addMouseWheelListener(this);
    scPane.add(CT3);
    CT3.setBounds(10, 10, 510,CT3.y);
    scPane.validate();
    scPane.repaint();

    cnt.add(scPane);
```

And in AdjustmentListener i have written following code:

```
public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) 
{
    int y = (int)(e.getValue()*3.2);
    CT3.reshape (10,(int)-Math.ceil(y)+25,510,CT3.y);
    CT3.validate();
    CT3.repaint();
}
```

And I have Dynmically calculated the size of CT3 as per following code

```
public void resize()
{
    if(itemVect.size()<=17)
    {
        pnlAnex.setBounds(0, 50, 510, 700);
    }
    else
    {
        int size=itemVect.size();
        y=(size*30)+90;
        pnlAnex.setBounds(0, 50, 510, y+50);
        pnlAnex.validate();
        pnlAnex.repaint();
        
    }
 }
```

But I am not getting the desired output.
The CT3 panel is showing correct height but the scrollpane is getting more height as per shown below image.
[image: Scrollpane]

The green part is of ScrollPane & the White part is of my desired output.

As you can see my scrollbar is still scrollable even if my desired output(White Panel) is dispalyed.

Please help me out to limit the scroll bar till my white panel is visible only(CT3 Panel)

Thanks in advance......

Comment: Forget to mention, my pnlAnex is added on CT3 Panel.

Comment: Use LayoutManager instead. E.g. GridLayout or GirdBagLayout. According to the screenshot it would be better to define JTable than reinvent wheel

Comment: Sorry,doesn't any changed anything